# Where can I travel from London and return to London with single entry UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk

Where can I travel with single entry UK visa? I have a Schengen visa as well. If I possess a single entry UK visa, can I travel to Schengen zone from London and return to London?
I am an Indian passport holder.

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: You could go to Scotland and Wales which we often call separate countries.

Comment: You can travel freely within the UK.  I am not certain whether you can travel to other jurisdictions in the common travel area, such as Ireland, and then return to the UK.  You certainly cannot Leanne the common travel area and then return to the UK, so no, you cannot go to Schengen and return to the UK.

Comment: Is this 'single-entry visa' something you actually have? Or a conjecture?

Comment: Oops! *Leave,* not Leanne.  Have to remember to proofread!

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the Schengen zone and then try to go back to the UK it will be another entry, and as your visa is single entry, you're not allowed. And there is border control at the UK border for passengers arriving from the Schengen zone.

Answer (score 2):

Once you cross the UK borders, your visa is considered "used".

Since yours is only for a single entry, it is no longer valid for entry. You can stay in the UK as long as the provisions of your visa permit, once you exit the UK - you will need a new visa.

As the UK is not party to Schengen, your Schengen visa is not valid for entry into the UK.